# Replacing directory-files-recursively with a list of files newer than 7 days old

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I currently use the following to get a list of agenda files for org-mode:

`(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively "~/Org" "\\.org$"))`

I'd like to instead get a list of files that are newer than 7 days old so that Emacs doesn't spend a long time reading and parsing all the org files I have.

I know I have to write a `defun` that takes in a directory and file regex as its 2 parameters, but I'm at a loss with how to then find files newer than 7 days.

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of a question that asked about using recent files. Hopefully someone will find the duplicate and then this question should be closed as a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the directory for files newers than 7 days

```
(defun newer-than-7-days(file)
  (> 7
     (/(float-time(time-subtract
                   (current-time )
                   (nth 5 (file-attributes file)) ))
       86400)))

(setq org-agenda-files
      (seq-filter #'newer-than-7-days 
                  (directory-files-recursively "~/Documents/Org" "\\.org$")))
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! You are an awesome person. Do you have a favourite charity I can donate to as a way of saying thank you?